# I am trying to save data in cookie but facing issue in the code as it is underlined by a red line

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code in registation.aspx

```
string loginid=loginId;
        string passwrd= password;
        int verified= Verified;
        int idType = IdType;
        string username= UserName;      
        DateTime dateCreated = DateTime.Now;

        tbl_user_login objUser = new tbl_user_login();
        result=objUser.registerUser(loginid, passwrd, verified, idType, username, dateCreated);


        HttpCookie cook = Request.Cookie("UserLoginId");
        if (cook != null)
        { 

            //show the user login id here
        }
```

This is the code of the class tbl_ser_login file

```
 HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserLoginId");
            myCookie["loginid"] = result.ToString();
            Response.Cookie.Add(myCookie);
```

In both of them the Response is showing red underlined and also it is showing as 'Response" does not exist in the current context.

These Libraries are included in class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

Comment: Try using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response`. Also confirm `System.Web` reference is added and listed in using section.

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response is not popping out in intellegence.  Syetem.Web is already added in the .cs file